# Apply Try with Resources correctly in Java 7?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, sonarqube, try-catch

I am developing an application with Angular and Spring with Java 7, however, I was asked to scan my code with SonarQube, so this tool is telling me that I need to apply a try with resources to close my **Prepared Statement** and **Result Set**, so I did some research and I implemented it like this:

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            PreparedStatement sentence = connection.prepareStatement(selectSql);
            ResultSet resultSet = sentence.executeQuery();) {
    

        // Create and execute a SELECT SQL statement.
        sentence.setString(1, parametro);
        logger.info(resultSet + " resultSet!----------------------------------------");

        // Print results from select statement
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            logger.info(" Entro al While!----------------------------------------");
            euroList.add(new EuroModel(resultSet.getInt("ID"), resultSet.getString("RFC"),
                    resultSet.getString("NOM")));
            logger.info("recibiendo result-> " + resultSet.getString(2) + " " + resultSet.getString(3));
            logger.info(euroList.toString());

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info("No se pudo conectar");
        logger.info("EuroService");
        logger.info("INFO: " + e);
        List<EuroModel> empty = null;
        return empty;
    }
```

However, my code is not working due to the following line is in the wrong place and I don't know where should it be with this try with resources:

```
sentence.setString(1, parametro);
```

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing your query before you have set your PreparedStatement’s parameter.

You can remove the ResultSet from your try-with-resources, because [it will be closed automatically](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A `ResultSet` object is automatically closed when the `Statement` object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

You want to make sure you execute your PreparedStatement’s query, and obtain the corresponding ResultSet, after you have set your parameter:

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement sentence = connection.prepareStatement(selectSql)) {


    // Create and execute a SELECT SQL statement.
    sentence.setString(1, parametro);
    ResultSet resultSet = sentence.executeQuery();
    logger.info(resultSet + " resultSet!----------------------------------------");
```

### Update

A useful additional lesson to take away from this:  SonarQube is not an authority when it comes to good programming practices.  In fact, SonarQube is wrong about things on a semi-regular basis.

This is such a case.  Sonar is not smart enough to know that a ResultSet will be automatically closed when its parent Statement is closed.  Sonar only knows that there is a closable object which doesn’t appear to be explicitly closed in the code.

As Slaw suggested, you can make Sonar happy by using another try-with-resources for the ResultSet:

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement sentence = connection.prepareStatement(selectSql)) {


    // Create and execute a SELECT SQL statement.
    sentence.setString(1, parametro);
    try (ResultSet resultSet = sentence.executeQuery()) {
        logger.info(resultSet + " resultSet!----------------------------------------");

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            // etc.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah but if i do that SonarQube will mark the ResultSet as a vulnerability since is not closing according to it. So i need to make my code works and get a pass grade from SonarQube.

Comment: @ErickFinn Then, if you really must, you can nest another try-with-resources statement in the one you already have.

Comment: @ErickFinn Updated answer.

Comment: @VGR i know but my boss dont see it like that. The app must pass SonarQube no matter what.